# Where is corresponding /dev/dsp from Linux 2.6 in Linux 3.+?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel

I got a tutorial to write to `/dev/dsp` to play with audio, but I found no such device in Linux 3.16. What should I do?

Comment: Kernel? Don't you mean "Linux"?

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/dsp` is interface for OSS (Open Sound System) which has been deprecated in favor of ALSA sound system in 3.x and 4.x kernels.

Comment: and what's the alternative in 3.+?

Comment: Just go with alsa-lib.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/dsp` is populated by the `snd-pcm-oss` module. If you don't have this module, you don't have `/dev/dsp`. `/dev/dsp` emulates old audio devices, so probably you don't really need it.

You can solve your problem, finding out your audio device. You can use something like:

```
aplay -l
```

If the `snd-pcm-oss` is compiled as external module in your kernel, you can load it with :

```
modprobe snd-pcm-oss
```

This should create /dev/dsp. I am not sure if the name of the module is exactly that one, you need to check the list of available modules in your system.

Comment: what's the alternative device in 3.+?